# Block auto save on syntax errors with VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use auto save on pretty short after change delay and on focus change. Instead of using longer delay and disabling save on blur, I'd like to block saving when code syntax is incorrect. This way watch scripts wouldn't fire, and auto reloading servers, compilers etc not fail unnecessarily. Manual save should work. I was wondering if there's configuration option, existing extension or perhaps something in the extension API that could do this check?

Settings don't seem to contain an option related to this. I searched extension marketplace in vain.I don't have experience with writing extensions yet, but will try to check that route too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code 1.86, this will be possible by setting the `files.autoSaveWhenNoErrors` setting to `true`. Quoting from the defaultSettings.json pseudo-file:

> ```json
> // When enabled, will limit auto save of editors to files that have
> // no errors reported in them. Only applies when `files.autoSave` is enabled.
> "files.autoSaveWhenNoErrors": false,
> ```

See issue ticket [Auto Save only when there are no syntax errors #189895](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189895).