# VSCODE : Don't save if the file has any error

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosave

So I got one thing in mind while working on VSCode. While I am using the auto save afterDelay and I am working on something and the file has some error and I rest a second the file gets saved. What I want is I dont want VSCode to save the file if the file contains any error. Like maybe a syntax error on javascript or python.

Comment: If you want to make sure you can go back to the last version that worked, you should use version control instead, not rely on when the files will be saved (you do have to save them anyway before you can compile)

Comment: I don't think You understood what I meant to say.

Lets say you are working on a react project. And you wrote something like `<p>Hello</p`

So obviously this will cause a syntax error on the file and you can see the filename in red color also on the minimap of your file you can see where the error is, But if you have autosave enabled afterDelay it will autosave after 1 second or your defined time even if there was a error. This is default behaviour of VS Code, it saves file no matter what. So I want that if there is a error in the file VS Code should not autosave the file.

Comment: I understand what you want, but since I don't think that feature exists, I'm trying to find out why you need that. Are you working on a live system?

Comment: Yes. basically when working on a React project when I type code I have the AutoSave enabled so if there is an error react still reloads the window because the code was saved which shows error on the screen and I dont like that. 

Thats why I want when there is a syntax error it wont save the file automatically.

Comment: In your situation, I would actually disable AutoSave alltogether and save only when I want to see the effects of my change.

Comment: Actually I submitted this as a Feature request on github [#141868](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141868#issuecomment-1025679210) . If it gets 20 Votes hopefully it will get added on vscode 

If you dont mind, you can give it a upvote

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57563875/11107541